# Data explorer doesn't highlight "TOP" as query keyword

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, data-explorer, editor

The Data Explorer doesn't highlight "TOP" as a query keyword, even though it supports it (i.e. "`SELECT TOP 10 ...`").

Comment: I believe this is SQL Server-specific (Transact-SQL), so I don't think of this as a bug, seems more like a feature-request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature-request, but I do know that it was just a 8 char change and its now fixed / completed